# usar lista python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if op == "2":
   1 searching=str(input("ingrese cuit: "))
   2 cuit=total.index(searching) 
   3 name = 2- cuit  
   4 lastname= 1-cuit
   5 key= 1+cuit 
   6 searching= total.index[name, lastname, cuit, key]
   7 print(searching)
```

1. acá ingreso el cuit
2. acá me dice la posición de tal
3. acá busco el index de name
4. acá busco el index de lastname
5. acá busco el index de key los cuales siempre van a estar
6. acá pongo los valores recolectados anterior mente
7. acá trato de mostrarlos

El problema es que la función index solo trabaja con números. A pesar de que name sea 0 no me lo considera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que intentas obtener los datos de diferentes usuarios ordenados secuencialmente en una lista llamada *total*. Sería mejor que utilizases listas de listas, o diccionarios...pero creo que esto te servirá:

```
total = ['Agustin', 'Damore', 1, 'pass1', 'Jose', 'Sanchez', 2, 'pass2']

searching = int(input("ingrese cuit: "))

if searching in total:
    cuit_index = total.index(searching)

    name_index = cuit_index - 2
    lastname_index = cuit_index - 1
    key_index = cuit_index + 1

    name = total[name_index]
    lastname = total[lastname_index]
    key = total[key_index]

    print(name)
    print(lastname)
    print(key)
```

Primero el usuario introduce el valor del *cuit*, a continuación obtienes su indice en la lista *total*, así como los índices de *name*, *lastname* y *key* (teniendo en cuenta que se encuentran en posiciones relativas a *cuit*). Luego, con el **operador de rebanada** *[ ]* obtienes los datos de la lista *total* según los índices que calculaste.

Comment: hola zeross tu respuesta funciona perfecto.mi problema ahora es que muestra [4, 5, 6, 7] necesitaría saber como hacer para que muestre el string no la posición

Comment: Si tienes una lista con una serie de strings y quieres acceder a sus valores utilizando estos números que has generado, utiliza string = lista[numero]. No comprendo bien lo que tratas de hacer jeje.

Comment: Es decir, esas son las posiciones, pero para poder ayudarte necesito saber a que se refieren esas posiciones.

Comment: es una lista llamada total en la cual hay varios nombres, apellidos,cuit (numero unico de cada persona). ej                                               total=[nombre, apellido, cuit, contraseña, [nombre, apellido, cuit, contraseña] cada uno tiene una posición. en lo que me ayudaste fue en conseguir la posición de cada uno ahora necesito que retorne en contenido de la posición conseguida

Comment: Vale, parece que tienes una lista con todos los datos de cada usuario ordenados de forma secuencial. Sería mejor que hicieses listas de listas, o diccionarios...pero voy a editar la respusta a ver si es lo que buscas.

Comment: muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: No hay de que :)

Comment: Me equivoqué en una cosa, no hace falta usar un bucle, ya está corregido.

Comment: hola maestro lo podrias hacer como antes... ahora no funciona sin el bucle me tira error

Comment: Comparte el error e intentaré ayudar, pero si no te funciona me temo que no comprendí bien el problema, ya que el ejemplo que he propuesto si funciona.

Comment: ya solucione ese problema! muchas gracias por la ayuda ahora tengo que averiguar como borrar los objetos de las listas